# Array support for Pick<> from ts-toolbelt?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use `Object.P.Pick` from [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt) over this type:

```js
type User = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    posts: {
        id: string;
        title: string | null;
        body: string;
    }[] | null;
}
```

like this:

```js
type Test = Object.P.Pick<User, ["name" | "posts", "id" | "posts", "title" ]>
```

expecting this:

```js
type Test = {
    name: string;
    posts: {
        id: string;
        title: string | null;
    }[] | null;
}
```

but I'm instead getting this:

```js
type Test = {
    name: string;
    posts: [] | null;
}
```

The `[]` there seem to be `undefined[]`.

[According to this PR](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt/pull/81) support for arrays was added back in 2019. What am I doing wrong?